# Wordpress reading old version of php file, breaks site

Tags: php, wordpress

I added a function to the child theme `functions.php` to check if a plugin class exists. The code was something like

```
function check_class_exists() {
    if (class_exists('classname')) {
        echo "class exists";
    } else {
        echo "does not exist";
    }

}

check_class_exists();
```

It did the job, then threw a 'headers already sent error,' which is reasonable. I removed the function from the file and re uploaded it to the server. The same error message exists, and prints the line where the previously existing function was. Here is the error message:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/drstevf1/public_html/cyrenelabs/wp-content/themes/divi-child/functions.php:275) in /home1/drstevf1/public_html/cyrenelabs/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1210

The function php is only 267 lines now - there is now way it can call that function!

**How can I ensure that Wordpress reads the most recent version of the file? I only have FTP access.**

Comment: Sounds like maybe you have some kind of server caching enabled.

Comment: Yep server caching in apache/nginx might be the issue here

Answer (score 1):

The issue was indeed server side caching. Bluehost was very helpful in providing a solution via FTP.

In the /wp-content/mu-plugins directory, there is a file called `endurance-browser-cache.php`. By renaming the file, for example to `endurance-browser-cache.old`, visiting the site, and returning the name to `endurance-browser-cache.php`, WordPress will have had to force refresh the cache.

Good to know!

Comment: Glad you got that!